# How to create zknodes with ttl in Apache Zookeeper using Curator

Tags: java, maven, apache-zookeeper, apache-curator

I want to create `zknodes` with `ttl` in Zookeeper 3.5.3 beta.

The latest Curator Framework I can get through Maven is 3.3.0, but I've found out that support for this feature is already added in a future release, 3.4.0.

So my questions are

1. Is is possible to get an unreleased version through Maven dependency?
2. Can I use Curator 3.3.0 to create `zknodes` with `ttl`?

Comment: Curator 3.4.0 will have support for TTL nodes. There isn't a release date yet, but it should come soon. For now, you could build from source if you need the feature sooner.

Comment: I got the latest source and tried "maven package", but it didn't pass the tests. I supposed that 3.4.0 is not functional yet?

Comment: I apologize about that. We have flakey tests. If you really need something bypass the tests via: mvn -DskipTests -Darguments="-DskipTests" install